# How can i get WhatsApp like menu from BottomNavigationBar using flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to design a WhatsApp-like menu from BottomNavigationBar for one of my applications which is written in flutter.

I have tried designing with PopupMenuButton class but it will cover the BottomNavigation also.

I need a popup like menu which is above the BottomNavigationBar something like below

[image: Menu popup from NavigationBar]

Comment: There is no Widget that does exactly what you want. You will need to make it. If you want help, you need to first make an attempt at creating it yourself, and then users will help you debug issues you may find. StackOverflow is not a coding service.

Comment: @JoãoSoares thanks for your useful suggestion,I am here after trying several things and i have also mentioned it up there, here i am not expecting someone to write the code for me, i am asking for suggestions., thanks anyways

Comment: That's exactly the point. StackOverflow is not the right forum to ask for suggestions. Please check the guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `PopupMenuButton` opens up a menu just above the button so it blocked the bottom bar. I found a workaround, instead of using `PopupMenuButton`, try using a `BottomAppBar` with the `IconButton` as one of the children, then use `showBottomSheet`so it won't block the `BottomAppBar`.

Note: Most of my codes are just placeholders to mimic the layout of your image, you need to rewrite most of them to match your needs. The key is using `showBottomSheet` for your problem.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Container(
          height: 70,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.home),
              Icon(Icons.alarm),
              MyMiddleIcon(),
              Icon(Icons.album),
              Icon(Icons.assignment_ind),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        color: Colors.blueGrey[50],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyMiddleIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          showBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => Container(
                color: Colors.red[100],
                height: 250,
                width: double.infinity,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(Icons.home),
                        Icon(Icons.hot_tub),
                        Icon(Icons.hourglass_empty),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(Icons.home),
                        Icon(Icons.hot_tub),
                        Icon(Icons.hourglass_empty),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ));
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer and time ,i was using pageview with BottomNavigationBar and it was giving problem, your answer helped me a lot to understand my problem and resolve the issue